# How to find determinant of a linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant

I have the following mapping : $Ax = x - 2\langle\,x,v\rangle v$, where $v$ is a normalized vector from $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ .

I'm supposed to show that it is self-adjoint and orthogonal, which I've already done.

Further, I have to find the determinant of A, which is where I'm having trouble.

The exercise also has a part 2 :  Let $B: V → V$ be an orthogonal mapping with determinant $−1$ and $n - 1$ dimensional eigenspace for eigenvalue $1$. Show that there exists a normalized vector
$u$ ∈ V such that $Bx = x - 2\langle\,x,u\rangle u$.

EDIT: Thanks to [@ThomasAndrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews), I figured that part out.
Now, It's a bit more clear how to do part 2:

We know that $dimKer(B - I) = n-1$, which means the geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue $1$ is $n-1$, and we know that $detB = -1$, so am I correct to assume that $B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: You can try setting $v_1 :=v$ and extend it to an orthonormal basis $\{v_1 ,v_2 ,\cdots, v_n\}$  of $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick an orthonormal basis $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ of $V$ with $v_1=v.$ Then compute $Av_i$ in terms of this basis.

Then you can consider $A$ as a matrix over this basis, and, in this case, easily compute the determinant of the matrix.

Comment: “Pick a basis” doesn’t actually mean that you need to pick them, only know that such a basis exists. There are known ways to specifically construct an orthonormal basis which includes $v,$ but this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: So, I can just say: let ${v_1, .., v_n}$ be an orthonormal basis for V, such that $v_1 = v$. Now, I compute $Av_k$ for $k ∈ \{1, .. , n\}$ and I find that $Av_1 = -v$ and $Av_t = v_t$ for $t ∈ \{2, .. , n\}$. Does that make the matrix $ A = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Correct, @Mavi. ${}{}{}$